# Typdef in C, using * what does this do?

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I've used typedef before, but I've never used one with a pointer. What effect does this have on the typedef?

Code for reference:

```
typedef struct node NODE,  *PNODE, **PPNODE;
```

Comment: it's the same as `typedef struct node NODE; typedef struct node *PNODE; typedef struct node **PPNODE;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `struct node` you can replace it with `NODE`

Instead of using `struct node*` you can replace it with `PNODE`

Instead of using `struct node**` you can replace it with `PPNODE`

The statement can be broken down to

```
typedef struct node NODE;
typedef struct node* PNODE;   // PNODE is pointer to node
typedef struct node** PPNODE; // PPNODE is pointer to pointer to node
```

Comment: Are you sure about those last two? At the very least it is not clear. Should it not be "replace with PNODE" and "replace with PPNODE"?

Comment: @AnujGarg Maybe you misunderstood me (or me you). The answer still shows "can replace it with *PNODE" and "can replace it with **PPNODE". That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @AnujGarg It's not corrrect. "struct node *" is equivalent to "PNODE" not "*PNODE" as you have stated. I'm referring to the description above the code fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The single `typedef` line defines three type aliases. The second and third are "pointer to `node`" and "pointer to pointer to `node`" respectively.

It may be easier to understand if split into three statements:

```
typedef struct node NODE;
typedef struct node *PNODE;   // PNODE is pointer to node
typedef struct node **PPNODE; // PPNODE is pointer to pointer to node
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't affect the typedef, it affects the type.

- `PNODE` is a pointer to `struct node`
- `PPNODE` is a pointer to a pointer to `struct node`